# Converting regular text input into DD/MM/YYYY format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can only use `type="text"` and I'm planning to get the format `DD/MM/YYYY` as the user types in the input field.

So far, I manage to get `DD/MM/YY/Y`. The year should be in `YYYY` format. How do I go about this?

```js
$('[data-type="date"]').keyup(function() {
      var value = $(this).val();
      value = value.replace(/\D/g, "").split(/(?:([\d]{2}))/g).filter(s => s.length > 0).join("/");
      $(this).val(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" data-type="date" maxLength="10" id="date" class="form-control" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try and use an external plugin for this. A quick search shows a few including [this one](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/).

Here's how it should work:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.date').mask('00/00/0000');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="date">
```

Don't forget to validate the input, though.

Comment: I recommend using an external plugin, and this one seems to work well. This is difficult to get right - there are a lot of edge cases.

Comment: It's time consuming to write this on you own

Comment: This looks good. Let me see if I can possibly add the external JS. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following solution to convert regular text input into `DD/MM/YYYY` format:

```
$('[data-type="date"]').keyup(function(event) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (event.keyCode !== 8 && value.indexOf("/") === value.lastIndexOf("/")) {
        if (value.length > 2 && value[2] != "/") {
            value = value.substring(0, 2) + "/" + value.substring(2);
        } 

        if (value.length > 5 && value[5] != "/") {
            value = value.substring(0, 5) + "/" + value.substring(5);
        }
    }
    $(this).val(value);
});
```

Comment: Looks good but it disables deleting the DD/MM. Type out and then try to delete using backspace key: http://jsfiddle.net/x4n2vwuj/

Comment: check the keycode of the keyup event and if it's the backspace key, don't append the slash

Comment: What are you trying to say? @pseudobbs

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery Mask Plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/). For [installation information](https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin#install-it-via-package-managers)

```js
$('[data-type="date"]').mask('00/00/0000');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" data-type="date" maxLength="10" id="date" class="form-control" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">
```

Comment: This has a couple of weird behaviors. 1) the `/` does not show up until you type the next number, and you cannot type the `/` yourself. 2) if you type a date, then go back and edit the `MM` field (for example, add some numbers), then the date is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want. It uses [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to put the `/'s` into the date string, testing to see if we are past the month, or already at the end of the string so as not to put in a `/` where it should not occur.

```js
$('[data-type="date"]').keyup(function() {
      var value = $(this).val();
      value = value.replace(/\D/g, "")
                   .split(/(..)/)
                   .filter(s => s.length > 0)
                   .reduce((t, v, i, a) => t + v + (i > 1 || i == a.length - 1 ? '' : '/'), '');
      $(this).val(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" data-type="date" maxLength="10" id="date" class="form-control" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">
```

Comment: This also has some very annoying behavior when trying to change only the days or the months.

Comment: Thank You. I don't know who downvoted you :( but thank you again for the effort. Like @halfpastfour.am pointed out, there's an annoying behaviour while editing.

Comment: @ElaineByene No worries I had a lot of fun thinking about it. Pity about the editing behaviour, I hadn't noticed that... must think about it some more.